# What causes TerminateProcess: Access is denied. when trying to run a Symfony server on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, symfony, process, access-denied

## Context

I am using Symfony for a website and I worked on it during around two weeks.

I'm on Windows 10, I use Symfony 5.8.12 and php 8.1.13 along with Wamp 3.3.0 for the database.
Everything worked normally until last Friday :

I tried refreshing a page but the loading was endless. There were no additional symfony logs.
I stopped the server from running using Ctrl+C and it stopped when looking at the processes in task manager.
I got the message :

```
  TerminateProcess: Access is denied.
```

I tried `symfony server:start`
I got the same message I again, but why ? **I am trying to run it not terminate it**.

**Edit :I also discovered that Access is denied error I get is most likely because of the following, when running** `symfony server:status`:
[image: Server not running but Worker assigned to a non existent PID/Non symfony related PID]

## What I ended up doing as a temporary solution

**Edit : I have admin rights now so it's not that big of a deal. I can logout then login again to solve the issue. The problem is it's happening several times on random days or times of the day.**

The solution that worked was restarting the computer, but since I don't have my admin rights yet, I need the IT staff to enter admin credentials to execute Wamp.

I also tried using `symfony server:start -d` so that whenever I wanna stop the server I use the proper command, `symfony server:stop`.

## What happened today and why I am posting on stackoverflow

Today, again I worked on my project for the day and everything went all good and my webpack compiled but the console in the dev tools didn't want to update my javascript code so I restarted symfony with `symfony server:stop` to which I get :

```
Stopping Web Server
```

Then I run `symfony server:start` and I get

```
TerminateProcess: Access is denied.
```

#### Questions

**Edit - Why is the PID still assigned to a worker according to Symfony and is there a way to reset this "binding" without logging out ?**
Why do I get this message about *TerminateProcess* when I am not terminating but starting the process ?
Why does this happen kind of randomly ? (it happened once directly after a reboot, today after a whole day working normally...).

Comment: No joke, I’d try rebooting a bunch to annoy IT into granting admin credentials. That said, if you are running the Symfony CLI binary, then the WAMP is just MySQL, maybe consider installing a dedicated copy of that which auto starts with the computer. Or, look into WSL, that’s what I do on my Windows machines.

Comment: @ChrisHaas , I am getting the admin access rights soon enough.
It just drives me crazy how the problem happens so randomly...

One possible cause I was told is, as I am not an admin, the process doesn't stop correctly and also because I am not an admin I can't see wether it's still running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [CrSrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12131398/crsrr) I found a way to "solve" this problem on the go (without having to logout/restart the computer) though it doesn't explain why, as shown in the OP's terminal screenshot, symfony keeps a Worker bound to the nonexistent PID.

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64235602/18466273) to a post that didn't specifically mention the `TerminateProcess` error, but that talked about symfony Workers being duplicated and bound to dead PIDs.

The solution is to delete the folder corresponding to the name of the log file mentioned after a `server:status`.

In our case the log file specified in Workers is **973a...1476.log**.
And so we delete the folder **C:\Users\%USER%\.symfony5\var\973a...1476\**
We can then check its status, it should be as the following, and we can start our server again.
[image: symfony server:status result - Not Running and No Workers]

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work on every occasion, as I tried it today so I will keep it as a potential solution but it is not the proper fix.
An [issue](https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/issues/244) discussing this was opened on symfoni-cli repo in 2022.